# how to run g:profiler

Tags: python, macos, unix, conda

I'm new to bioinformatics, and am learning to use g:profiler.

The advice I got was:

```
# Install the client.
pip install gprofiler-official  #this works fine, and says "Requirement already satisfied"

#Get help on the client parameters.
gprofiler_cli.py --help 

#the output I get is:
$ gprofiler_cli.py --help
-bash: gprofiler_cli.py: command not found
(base) 

# Example run from the documentation.
gprofiler_cli.py -o scerevisiae "swi4 swi6" 

#the output I get is:
$ gprofiler_cli.py -o scerevisiae "swi4 swi6"
-bash: gprofiler_cli.py: command not found
(base)
```

I'd be grateful for any help as I'm stuck, despite reading around the internet Thanks!

Comment: FYI I'm using terminal on a mac

Comment: It fails to find the program, it is probably because it's not in the $PATH. Are you working in any kind of virtualenv ?

Comment: `gprofiler_cli.py` doesn't exist anymore. See: https://github.com/biostars/biostar-handbook/issues/138